# Calculating maximum length of AES encrypted message

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I'm using this function to encrypt data using openssl AES 256 CBC:

```
int encryptAES(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
  unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

  int len;

  int ciphertext_len;

  /* Create and initialise the context */
  if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) return handleErrors();

  /* Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
   * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
   * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
   * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
   * is 128 bits */
  if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
    return handleErrors();

  /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
   * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
   */

  if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
    return handleErrors();
  ciphertext_len = len;

  /* Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
   * this stage.
   */

  if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) return handleErrors();
  ciphertext_len += len;

  /* Clean up */
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

  return ciphertext_len;
}
```

I want to provide to this function a fixed sized buffer `ciphertext`, How can I calculate the maximum possible length of the encrypted message (`ciphertext`)

Thanks.

Comment: Round `ciphertext` up to a multiple of 16.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming PKCS#7 padding, which is the default for OpenSSL ECB and CBC mode, the encrypted length will be:

```
plaintext_len + block_size - (plaintext_len % block_size)
```

where

```
block_size = 16
```

for AES. The end result is always a multiple of `block_size`.

Comment: Isn't it IV + message + padding? Thus `block_size + plaintext_len + (block_size - (plaintext_len % block_size))`.

Comment: Yes if  the IV is prepended to the encrypted data. While that is often done and a good way to handle the IV it is not part of AES. There are several other things that are often prepended such as KDF salt and iteration count.

Comment: I've somewhat changed the answer as PKCS#5 is a subset of PKCS#7 for 8-byte block ciphers - and AES is a 16 byte block cipher. So the name within Java ("PKCS5Padding" is incorrect). More information [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification WRT OpenSSL. I understand and unfortunately many implementations specify padding as PKCS#5 for AES, a hold over from a pre-AES implementation. That is why the (née PKCS#5) where "née"means "Formerly known as", see [http://www.The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nee). Perhaps there is a better way to let people know that for many implementations PKCS#7 padding is specified as PKCS#5.

Comment: *"Isn't it IV + message + padding?"* - No. The encryption transformation does not encrypt the IV. Intuitively, if the IV was encrypted and perhaps prepended to the message, then one could not perform decryption because the IV would not be available. In essence, you would need the plaintext IV to decrypt the encrypted IV which would be the original IV itself.